# How to directly reuse a function returned from another one in F#

Tags: f#

I'm currently working on a project where I have to create a lot of functions according to some rules and reuse those functions later. And for that I started to learn F#, just seemed to be a more natural thing to do in F# than in C#.

I managed to create the functions as they should be but I have some problems whith reusing them. Below is a very simplified example, to show what I'm trying to do.

```
let choice = 2

let fCreator (x:float) =
    match choice with
    |1 ->  x * x
    |2 ->  x * 10.0
    |3 ->  x + 20.0
    |_ ->  x
```

I have a global variable choice according to which in fCreator a transformation of x is selected and returned. This works fine by calling it e.g.

```
let result1 = fCreator 1.0
```

But the problem is that I have to use the selected transformation (in that case x*10) for a lot different inputs and when using it this way

```
let result2 = fCreator 2.0
let result3 = fCreator 3.0
.
.
.
```

then the whole selection process is done again, which is no big deal here but my actual selection function is a far more complicated one and takes some time to compute.

Is it possible to call fCreator, get and save the selected transformation and then directly use it? Something like

```
let selectedFunction x:float = fCreator x:float
```

where then

```
selectedFunction x:float = x * 10
```

is

I know the above wont work that way, but I hope you get the idea what I'm trying to do. selectedFunction then should be the chosen transformation from fCreator.

I'm quite new to F# so I might be overlooking something obvious but I perused several Q&As according to function caching in F#. But as far as I can see neither memoizing nor lazy evaluation will do what I'm looking for.

I also tried to write fCreator as a void function with x in the body as a declared but not initialized variable and then returning a transformation with that variable. But it didn't quite work out and is as much as I know also not the proper way to do in F#.

I hope that someone could give me a hint here.

Comment: I would imagine that moving choice to a free variable / parameter of the function would make your life easier. Then you can apply `choice` in a partial function call (returning a new "fCreator" function that only has `x` free). See [F# partial functions](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/10/13/f-and-first-class-functions-part-3-partial-function-application/) and [partial application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233229(v=vs.100).aspx), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on a global value, define a function that returns another function:

```
let selectCreator choice =
    match choice with
    | 1 -> fun x -> x * x
    | 2 -> fun x -> x * 10.0
    | 3 -> fun x -> x + 20.0
    | _ -> id
```

This is a function that returns the desired function. It has the signature `int -> (float -> float)`. You can bind it to a particular choice like this:

```
let creator = selectCreator 2
```

You can now use `creator` with various values:

```
> creator 2.0;;
val it : float = 20.0
> creator 3.0;;
val it : float = 30.0
```

The selection only happens when you invoke `selectCreator`; every time you call `creator`, you simply call the returned function. This can be illustrated by making the following modification to `selectCreator`:

```
let selectCreator choice =
    match choice with
    | 1 ->
        printf "1 selected"
        fun x -> x * x
    | 2 ->
        printf "2 selected"
        fun x -> x * 10.0
    | 3 ->
        printf "3 selected"
        fun x -> x + 20.0
    | _ ->
        printf "Default selected"
        id
```

Although in Functional Programming, we dislike side-effects, it's a great way to demonstrate that this works as intended. Here's a log of an FSI session:

```
> let creator = selectCreator 2;;
2 selected
val creator : (float -> float)

> creator 4.0;;
val it : float = 40.0

> creator 5.0;;
val it : float = 50.0
```

Notice that it only prints out the selection when `creator` is selected, not when it's invoked.

This approach also has the advantage that you change your mind at run-time, and select a different function:

```
> let creator3 = selectCreator 3;;
3 selected
val creator3 : (float -> float)

> creator3 4.0;;
val it : float = 24.0
> creator3 5.0;;
val it : float = 25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the choice is computed once and then always the same, then you can do something like this:

```
let choice = 2

let fCreator =
    match choice with
    | 1 -> fun x -> x * x
    | 2 -> fun x -> x * 10
    | 3 -> fun x -> x + 20
    | _ -> x
```

This will return a whole different function depending on the value of `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, reusing a function "returned from another one". You can do it like this:

```
let mkCreator choice = function
    | 1 -> fun x -> x * x
    | 2 -> ( *) 10.0
    | 3 -> (+) 20.0
    | _ -> id

let fCreator = mkCreator 2
fCreator 20.0               (* val it = 200.0 : float *)
```

This makes the "expensive" `mkCreator` call happen only once.

---

Another answer suggested the following:

```
let mkCreator choice x = function
    | 1 -> x * x
    | 2 -> (*) 10.0
    | 3 -> (+) 20.0
    | _ -> x

let fCreator = mkCreator 2
```

However, the body of `mkCreator` won't be evaluated until it has *all* of it's arguments. That means that every time you subsequently apply `fCreator`, you will evaluate the body of `mkCreator`. But this was exactly what we were trying to avoid!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your responses!

So the overall idea is to use anonymous functions as return values in my selection function. This works perfectly fine and is a simple way to do in the above examples.

But the problem is (at least for me) that in my actual selection function the transformations are created through lots of recursive function calls, which makes it not that easy to define them as anonymous functions. The created transformations (like e.g. `x*x` above) then are actually sequences of operations and recursive functions and best thing would have been to let them unchanged.

I hoped it might be possible to store the selected transformation only by changing the code that calls the selection function. So that I could get something like the `creator` function in Mark's example, but keeping the return values in `selectCreator` as they are in my original example (not as anonymous functions).

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you're trying to do, but you might want to look at [memoization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx?Redirected=true) as a possible solution.

Comment: It's customary to put this sort of follow-on questioning as an edit to your question (and maybe also add comments to other answers if you have followups re them and/or want to alert them to the fact that you've provided more info in your question which may help them improve their answer's relevance to you). As this is, a) nobody will be aware of this info when answering b) none of the existing responders will see it either.